# Disable F1 on xfce terminal

Tags: xfce, terminal-emulator

I'm not using XFCE as a desktop environment, but I am using XFCE's terminal. Currently, when I press F1, I get the help. I really don't need this, and it's really annoying when I accidentally press it when in VIM when trying to press escape.

I didn't see anywhere in Preferences to change/disable keyboard shortcuts. Is there some hidden way to disable these shortcuts?

If it matters, I'm running xmonad on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This page](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/xfce-terminal-cannot-bind-shortcut-keys-how-do-i-disable-all-shortcuts-884621/) recommends adding blank accellator shortcuts to ~/.config/Terminal/terminalrc'. I run XFCE 4.8 and could not find this file myself. However, in my terminal preferences (under Edit), there is a shortcut tab. Help = F1 is the last shortcut in the list. My terminal emulator version is 0.4.8. Hopefully one of these will be applicable to you.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work for me. I'm running xfce4-terminal 0.6.1 for Xfce 4.10. I don't seem to have a shortcut tab... weird...

Comment: If I read correctly, then apparently if you however the mouse over the menu option for help, and press a new key, it will rebind to that key instead and free up F1. [link](http://docs.xfce.org/faq). Seems dubious but it is worth a try.

Comment: Post #5 [here](http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=7720) suggests editing ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm

Comment: That dubious link seemed to work. I had to restart X, but I was able to delete the shortcut. Thanks!

Comment: Under ubunto 14.04 I found the config file under .config/xfce4/terminal

Answer (score 30):

Copied from [Function Key Binding in XFCE](http://xfce.10915.n7.nabble.com/Function-Keys-binding-in-Xfce-Terminal-tp42414p42417.html) and the [FAQ](http://docs.xfce.org/faq):

1. Run `xfce4-appearance-settings`.
2. Click **Settings** tab.
3. Check **Enable editable accelerators**.
4. Click **Close**.
5. Open an xfce terminal.
6. Click the **Help** menu.
7. Hover over **Contents** (do not click).
8. Press the <kbd>Del</kbd> key to delete the accelerator.

<kbd>F1</kbd> disappears from the menu item.

The fullscreen accelerator, <kbd>F11</kbd>, can be removed similarly:

1. Click **View**
2. Hover over **Fullscreen**.
3. Press <kbd>Del</kbd>.

Pressing any other key than <kbd>Del</kbd> reassigns the accelerator key to the key that was pressed.

Comment: Did not work for me on Xubuntu 16.04. @marco 's answer worked.

Comment: Worked using Xubuntu 16.04.1.

Comment: This answer no longer works since Xfce Terminal moved to GTK+3: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=841870

Comment: Did not work for me, Fedora 30, XFCE 4.12

Answer (score 12):

At least for xfce-terminal of `version 0.8.6` or higher there is an option within preferences, where this can be easily set.

[image: Terminal Preferences with option to disable F1]

Yeah, this may seem obvious. I posted this in order for people landing here from their favourite search engine to know there is much easier way to solve the problem *now*.

Answer (score 9):

on xubuntu 12.04 with xfce4-terminal 0.6.1 (Xfce 4.10)
I've resolved adding:

in ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/fullscreen" "")
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/contents" "")
```

and
in ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc

```
AccelFullscreen=
AccelContents=
```

so both F1 help/contens
and F11 fullscreen are disabled

Comment: Editing `accels.scm` alone works for me (version 0.6.1 on Arch).

Comment: On Xubuntu 13.10 using xfce4-terminal 0.6.2. I created `accels.scm` with content above, not changing terminalrc, then closed all opened terminal windows. Then launching a new terminal window had the expected behavior: now F1 is passed to applications (e.g. `mc`).

Answer (score 0):

Creating an `accels.scm` file also worked (without changes to `terminalrc`) in Xubuntu 13.04. Not sure why!