# Disable F11 (fullscreen) in XFCE Terminal

Tags: xfce4, terminal-emulator

This is a lot like [disable F1 on xfce terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/562069).  But:

- I want to disable F11, not F1.  Disabling F1 is in the preferences UI (which works), but F11 is not there.
- I've tried everything mentioned at that question (accels.scm, terminalrc), it does not work, F11 still toggles full-screen.

I've got xfce4-terminal version 0.8.5.1.  I want applications inside my terminal to see and use F11 keypresses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the Xfce Terminal moved to GTK+3, editable accelerators are no longer effective.

However editing `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm` stills works. There should be a commented-out line mapping F11 to fullscreen. Replace this line with an empty accelerator:

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/fullscreen" "")
```

Comment: The Gnome Disease: knowing shit better than the user.  (AKA the Havoc Pennington Disease)

We should be "thankful" they left a setting for this *somewhere*.  For now…

Comment: good grief it's 4 years later and I still had to do this this way just now